# API call to get jenkins credential secret text value

Tags: jenkins

I need help to fetch the jenkins credential secret text value via API , so that I can use it at some other task in ansible. I have follow this link for that but not sure how to store the secret value as plain text in variable. Can someone please help

https://tutorials.releaseworksacademy.com/learn/how-to-add-jenkins-credentials-with-curl-or-ansible

The above link explains for post method but I want to use GET method and store the secret value as plain text